# goodman limit switch problem

Tags: switch

I have a 2013 goodman 3T gas pack. It is being intermittent and telling me there is a limit switch problem (4 blinks). I try to catch it when it goes off which is about every other day, but by the time I get the panel off it starts up again. It is not the RS because I jumped it out and it still quit. That only leaves the ALS and LS. It is acting like a loose/broken connection because it appears to restart as soon as something is touched but I can't nail it down. I reseated the connectors and moved around others to verify connections.

Otherwise the unit runs fine. If I catch it when it is off, I will have the answer, but between the ALS, LS, transformer, or a broken connection (maybe on the PCB) which is most likely to fail?

Comment: Please don't use initialisms (at least without defining them first). We're a community of laypeople and that makes your post a very confusing read.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need a clearer question before we can answer it. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Unfortunately, my stepson is an HVAC guy and he can't figure it out. I have no idea what those letters stand for except RS is rollout switch, als is alternate Lsomething switch and LS is, I guess, Lsomething switch. Somehow I thought there might be people here who had some experience and might guess what the issue is. It quit again and I think I detected a loose connector so I tried expanding the pin. I'll see how that works.OH, PCB is printed circuit board.I'm an engineer and lived with that for 60 years so I thought everyone knew it.